# Image not displaying in view (laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using laravel 5.2. I am building a post system in which user comment on it by **clicking the given images**.

The path for image is fetched correctly but **it is not displayed in the view**.Also there is no error given in the view.

my controller:

```
public function createemoji($action,$statusId)
{


    $path=('/images/'.$action.'.gif');





   $request=new storage();
    $request->comment=$path;
    $request->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $request->post_id=$statusId;
    $request->save();









     $storage=storage::where(function($query) use($statusId)
     {
         $query->where('post_id',$statusId)
            ;
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    dd($storage);

  return redirect()->back()->with('storage',$storage);
}
```

my view:

```
<a href="{{route('createemoji',['action'=>'6796','statusid'=>$post->id])}}" id="6796" class="btn btn-sm"><img id="z1" src="/images/6796.gif" name="one"/></a>
```

the way i am trying to display:

```
  @foreach($storages as $storage)
   @if($storages==$post->storage)


<div class="row">
<section class=" col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">

<h4 id="h45"></h4>
<img src="{{ $storage->comment }}">


</section>
</div>


 @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the full path for *img-src* like below:

```
<img id="z1" src="www.yourdomain.com/images/6796.gif" name="one"/>
```

Further you can check by inspecting image element using your browser inspect tool. For example in [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/?hl=en).

Comment: it will work only for single image.I want to display all images of that post.

Comment: Did you check `$storage->comment` value for every image. May be this return incorrect data?

Comment: And what is the src, if you inspect for correct and incorrect image tag?

Comment: <img src="/images/6796.gif">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125231/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-yash-chaudhary).